# decreasing in size when reversing and storing text from a file to another using Java

Tags: java

I made this homework exercise to read text from a text file and store it reversed into another new file. This is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

  public class FileEcho {

File file;
Scanner scanner;
String filename = "words.txt";
File file1 ;
            PrintWriter pw ;
void echo() {
    try {
        String line;

        file = new File( filename);
        scanner = new Scanner( file );
        file1 = new File("brabuhr.txt");
        pw = new PrintWriter(file1);


        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            String s = new StringBuilder(line).reverse().toString();

            pw.println(s);
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println( "Could not find or open file <"+filename+">\n"+e 
 );
    } 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new FileEcho().echo();
}
 }
```

and here is a picture [Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyB5n.png)

**The question is: why is the newly generated file decreased in size despite having the same characters but reversed?**

Would be great if someone can explain it because even my professor didn't know why is that.

P.S; the context of the file is just some words from the dictionary.
Also in other students computers so the problem is not from my computer

Comment: Why is that what? In other words, what result is so inexplicable? Did you by any chance run this on Windows and did you calculate the difference between the `\n\r` of the original file and the `\n` you wrote?

Comment: So you're writing `brabuhr.txt` and reading `words.txt`? For future development I'd suggest naming the variables accordingly since that will make it easier to understand the code quickly.

Comment: @M.leRutte The size of the files is different.

Comment: See my comment edit.

Comment: Did you compare the files to see what the actual differences are? If the size is different the content must be as well.

Comment: Check with a hexviewer and you will see the difference.

Comment: The files context is different because it is all reversed.

Comment: The issue could be an encoding. Some languages (such as Arabic) may be encoded in different charsets, or some letters in Arabic may have different codes in the same charset (old for backwards compatibility) and new ones. Check your files if they are in different charsets. If they have the same charsets modify your program to copy file as is (and not reversed) and then compare the contents

Comment: @MichaelGantman The language used is Dutch and there are no weird things like Arabic or so and I just checked it non-reversed and still the same results

Comment: Nope - the comments above are wrong. `pw` isn't closed, so not flushed.

Comment: @M. Ie Rutte most likely is correct about the writer not being flushed. But in any case if you have non-reversed copy you can compare the contents of the 2 files and see the difference in the contents. That most likely will explain the difference in size

Comment: @AbdulMalekAltawekji Given that I actually took some time to investigate your problem, what about accepting the answer?

Comment: @M.leRutte Sorry for my late response. I don't have any problem with the output but i can't find an answer that is really one and it made me more curious when our prof didn't have an explanation for it. It is just pure curiosity.

Comment: But have you tried `close`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you never closed the output stream `pw`, so that any pending output isn't written to the underlying file. This may cause truncation of your file.

You should have closed the output stream with `pw.close()` in a `finally`, or in a try with resources.

```
try (pw = new PrintWriter(file1)) {
   while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      line = scanner.nextLine();
      String s = new StringBuilder(line).reverse().toString();
      pw.println(s);
  }
}
```

Your implementation can be simplified to be the following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FileEcho {
    void echo() throws IOException {
        try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("brabuhr.txt")) {
            Files.lines(Paths.get("words.txt"))
                .map(s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString())
                .forEach(pw::println);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new FileEcho().echo();
    }
}
```

In this example I used a 'try-with-resources' to have the `PrintWriter pw` autoclosed.